# Mac won’t start up after deleting the Boot Camp Windows partition

Tags: macos, mac, boot-camp

I erased the Windows partition I had created using Boot Camp assistant and now my Mac is showing question mark on start up.

I have tried to reinstall macOS in recovery mode but it doesn’t work because the disk doesn‘t show up, then I tried to repair the disk using disk utility and it shows the following error:

```
nx_block_count is 29571062, while device block count is 20507899
```

Comment: Did you have a macOS partition on the machine as well that has data? Is that why you haven’t repartitioned the machine? Or are you fine starting with a clean slate and wiping the drive out to reinstall macOS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reformat/repartition your disk. You may be able to do this from recovery mode. Once you're in recovery mode, select Disk Utility and fix your partitioning/formatting before you run the OS installer.

Recovery mode, even Internet recovery mode, may still need to keep some files on the internal disk, so you might not be able to fully wipe and entirely repartition the internal drive. There are ways to install an OS installer image to an external drive like a USB Flash drive, and boot from that, so that your entire internal disk is available for repartitioning/formatting.

Comment: Basically, it means macOS finds on startup a disk with a bigger size than what is expected, given that you have deleted your Boot Camp partition. You have to perform a "sudo chkdsk /f" in Terminal (you'll find it in Applications / Utilities) while in Recovery Mode, or use Disk Utility (click on "Display all devices" in View), and click on the "SOS" button after selecting the volume you want checked in the left pane (do it for both volumes, System and Data).